# Unable to assign result of map() to 2-D list

Tags: python-3.x, cpython, python-internals

The below code is for taking a set of rows of students' marks in array, and need find the row with maximum marks.
Below is incomplete code, as need to search for the maximum sum row still; but stuck at the incomplete code due to error.

It gives below error in [py3.codeskulptor.org/](https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user303_e5IF5i9oZs_1.py), while in [Pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=%23%20Input%20number%20of%20test%20cases%20%0At%20%3D%20int%28input%28%22Input%20number%20of%20test%20cases%22%29%29%20%0A%0A%23%20Input%20size%20of%20rows%20%28of%20students%29%20%0An%20%3D%20int%28input%28%22Input%20size%20of%20columns%22%29%29%23.strip%28%29.split%28%29%29%20%0Aprint%20%28t,n%29%0A%0Aarr%20%3D%20%5B%5B%5B%5D%20for%20i%20in%20range%28t%29%5D%20for%20i%20in%20range%28n%29%5D%20%0Atotal%20%3D%20%5B%5B%5D%20for%20i%20in%20range%20%28n%29%5D%20%20%0A%0A%23%20One%20by%20one%20run%20for%20all%20input%20test%20cases%20%0Afor%20i%20in%20range%280,t%29%3A%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20Input%20score%20of%20each%20student%20in%20the%20column%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20sum%20%3D0%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20for%20j%20in%20range%28n%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20arr%5Bi%5D%5Bj%5D%20%3D%20map%28int,%20input%28%22Input%20score%22%29.strip%28%29.split%28%29%29%23%5B%3An%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%23the%20above%20line%20causes%20compilation%20error%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20Find%20sum%20of%20all%20scores%20row-wise%20%0A%20%20%20%20for%20m%20in%20arr%5Bi%5D%5Bj%5D%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sum%20%2B%3D%20m%0A%20%20%20%20total%5Bi%5D%20%3D%20sum1%0A%0A%23%20Find%20the%20max.%20of%20total%0Afor%20j%20in%20range%28t%29%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20y%20%3D%20max%28total%5Bj%5D%29&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%222%22,%223%22,%221%202%203%22,%222%203%204%22,%223%204%205%22%5D&textReferences=false), the program terminates at the same line number.

> > Line #17: IndexError: list assignment index out of range

```
# Input number of tests 
t = int(input("Input number of tests")) 

# Input size of rows (of students) 
n = int(input("Input size of rows"))#.strip().split()) 
print (t,n)

arr = [[[] for i in range(t)] for i in range(n)] 
total = [[] for i in range (n)]  

for i in range(0,t): 

    # Input score of each student in row     
    sum =0    
    for j in range(n):
        arr[i][j] = map(int, input("Input score").strip().split())#[:n]
    #the above line causes compilation error

    # Find sum of all scores row-wise 
    for m in arr[i][j]:
        sum += m
    total[i] = sum1

# Find the max. of total
for j in range(t): 
    y = max(total[j])
```

Please also suggest a crisper approach to program the above problem.

*P.S.* I found the above code to be nearly wrong, but kicked me in correct direction.

 Have the modified code below with a question that arose during debugging that concerns the :

> max() giving precedence to [] over an integer value

This behaviour of max() was detected when incorrectly stated line #13 as :

> total = [[[] for i in range (l)] for i in range (n)]

The correct working code is below, with output [image: here]:

```
# Input number of tests 
t = int(input("Input number of tests")) 

# Input number of rows (of students) 
n = int(input("Input number of rows"))#.strip().split()) 

# Input limit on number of students in a row (of students) 
l = int(input("Input max. number of studentsin any row"))#.strip().split()) 

print ('t :',t,'n :',n, 'l :', l)

arr = [[[[] for i in range(l)] for i in range(n)] for i in range(t)]
total = [[[] for i in range (n)] for i in range (t)]  

# run input of tests 
for i in range(t):   
    # Input score of each student in the i-th row, out of n   
    sum =0 
    for j in range(n):
        #for k in range(l):
        print("jkl:","i:",i,"j:",j)
        arr[i][j] = map(int, input("Input score").strip().split())[:l]


for i in range(t): 
    for j in range(n):
        # Find sum of all scores row-wise 
        sum = 0
        for m in arr[i][j]:
            #sum[i][j][] += m
            print ('m :', m)
            sum += m

        #total[i][j] = sum[i][j][]
        total[i][j] = sum

for i in range(t):
    print("Test no. ", i)
    for j in range(n):
        #for m in arr[i][j]:
        print (arr[i][j])
            #print (m)
    print("=========")

for i in range(t): 
    for j in range(n):
        print(i,"-",j, total[i][j])
    print("::::::")
print("=========")

# Find the max. of total
for i in range(t): 
     print([m for m in total[i]])
     y = max([m for m in total[i]])
     print ('i:',i,',', 'max total:',y)
```

Request reason for the precedence shown by max(), and if possible link the answer with some reference to underlying implementation in CPython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> arr = [[[] for i in range(t)] for i in range(n)]
> ```

Considering the above construction of `arr`, you have swapped `t` and `n` in the nested loops:

> ```
> for i in range(t):
>     # …
>     for j in range(n):
>         arr[i][j] = …
> ```

The first index into `arr` (corresponding to the *outer* loop) must be a number between 0 and *n*–1.

The second index into `arr` (corresponding to the *inner* loop) must be a number between 0 and *t*–1.

Comment: Please also suggest a crisper approach to program.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a mistake between t and n

i should be in `range(n)`

and j should be in `range(t)`